Expression of the Riemannian metric on the Siegel domain?
I'm looking for proof that, for the complex Siegel domain in $\mathbb C^{n}$ defined by:
$$\mathcal H_{n} = \{ z=(z_1,\dots,z_n) \in \mathbb C^{n} \mid \operatorname{Im}(z_{n}) > \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} |z_j|^2 \}$$
the Riemannian metric $ds^2_z$ is given by
\begin{align*}
ds^2_z =&\; \frac{1}{(\operatorname{Im}(z_{n}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |z_i|^2)^2}
                \bigg(
                    (\operatorname{Im}(z_{n}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |z_i|^2) 
                        \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} d z_j \otimes d \bar{z}_j
                        + \sum_{j,k=1}^{n-1} \bar{z}_j z_k d z_j 
                                            \otimes d\bar{z}_k \\
                &+ \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \big(
                    \bar{z}_j d z_j \otimes d\bar{z}_{n}
                        -z_j d z_{n} \otimes d \bar{z}_j
                    \big)
                    + \frac{1}{4} d z_{n} \otimes d \bar{z}_{n}
                \bigg).
\end{align*}
Someone can give me the proof of the expression of $ds^2_z$ or a reference where I can find the demonstration.
Thank you in advance
